# Why is tf.layers.batch_normalization unfused by default?

Tags: tensorflow

The [TensorFlow performance page](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#common_fused_ops) suggests using `fused=True` for `tf.layers.batch_normalization`.  However, the default is `fused=False`.

Why isn't fused the default?  Naively, I would expect fusion to produce identical results much faster.